# Laravel Collective Form and Custom Bootstrap component

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravelcollective

I have this submit button in my view,using Laravel Collective package:

```
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
```

and as you can see it add a Bootstrap class and create a button.

Now my purpose is to create a custom button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

that has a span to keep the glyphicon. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom macro to achieve this.

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#custom-macros

Unless you're planning to reuse it a lot, you'd be better of creating a partial instead.